# Subclassing NSInputStream to upload a particular portion of data from a local filepath

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstream, nsinputstream, cfreadstream

I am having a 100 MB of data in a single file. This 100 mb data will be divided virtually. i.e., I need to create an NSInputStream which points to different 5MB chunks.
This is possible by creating the stream with NSData.

But rather I'd like to know if I can have a NSInputStream which points to a range of data in the file ?

Comment: Why not use `NSFileHandle` instead?

Comment: basically i dont want to create several NSData instances of size 5MB. it eats up a lot of memory.

Comment: you should then create one part of 5MB at a time in some serial queue for instance

Comment: And you shouldn't. Create a `NSFileHandle` and read the appropriate bytes at any offset by doing `seekToFileOffset:`.

Comment: Here ill be uploading a very long file from my iOS App. Im concurrently uploading different parts of the same file. Also there can be several file uploads also. If I create the Data with a filehandle this uploading will take around 30MB which I dont want. That is why i thought of going with NSInputStream. But with the NSInputStream I cannot offset the read buffer. Or the only solution will be writing each 5MB data to a file and create an InputStream from that File ??

Answer (score 4):

If you want to upload a file by passing a `NSInputStream` instance to `NSURLRequest.HTTPBodyStream` you indeed have to create a subclass of `NSInputStream` and only stream the bytes you want to upload. Using `NSFileHandle` is not an option here.

Creating a subclass of `NSInputStream` that works with `NSURLRequest` is quite tricky, but fortunately here is a [great blog post](http://blog.bjhomer.com/2011/04/subclassing-nsinputstream.html) about how it can be accomplished.

[Here you can find a ready to use subclass of `NSInputStream` for this purpose](https://github.com/sebcode/ChunkInputStream).

You can feed `ChunkInputStream` with another `NSInputStream` reading a file and pass start position and number of bytes to read.

Swift example:

```
let fileInputStream = NSInputStream(fileAtPath: "/tmp/readme")
let inputStream = ChunkInputStream(inputStream: fileInputStream)
inputStream.startPosition = 2097152
inputStream.readMax = 1048576
```